# How do you make a Serde struct work with both borrowed and owned data?

Tags: rust, serde, serde-json

I want to make a Serde struct that is capable of being deserialized from either borrowed data (`serde_json::from_str`) or owned data (`serde_json::from_reader`).  I have read [Understanding deserializer lifetimes](https://serde.rs/lifetimes.html), and I understand the difference between the two trait bounds (`<'de, T> where T: Deserialize<'de>` and `<T> where T: DeserializeOwned`); what I want is a struct that implements both trait bounds, such that it can be used from either deserialization function.

The following code ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=979338e8ba8c46602b6d1a52bb5223d4)) refuses to compile:

```rust
use serde_json; // 1.0.56
use serde; // 1.0.114
use std::fs;
use std::io;
use std::borrow::Cow;

#[derive(serde::Deserialize)]
struct Resource<'s> {
    // The Cow should allow for either borrowed or owned data
    #[serde(borrow)]
    pub foo: Cow<'s, str>,
}

fn main() {
    {
        // Works as expected when referencing a string...
        let s = "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}";
        let resource: Resource = serde_json::from_str(s).unwrap();
    }
    {
        // ...but refuses to compile when reading from a file
        let file = fs::File::open("dummy.json").unwrap();
        let reader = io::BufReader::new(file);
        let resource: Resource = serde_json::from_reader(reader).unwrap();
    }
}
```

How do I make this struct work with both owned and borrowed data?  Is there a way to do something like `#[serde(borrow_optional)]`?

Answer (score 1):

([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=35dcff8d68cfab0a6d17f19a3ac1b022))

It's not possible with the constraints on `serde_json::from_reader`. However, it *is* possible if you construct `Deserializer` yourself:

```rust
        // ...but refuses to compile when reading from a file
        let file = fs::File::open("dummy.json").unwrap();
        let reader = io::BufReader::new(file);
        let mut deser = serde_json::Deserializer::from_reader(reader);
        let resource = Resource::deserialize(&mut deser).unwrap();
```